# How can I post an image from S3 to an external API using lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, linkedin-api

I am writing a lambda node function that needs to get an image from S3 then post it to the LinkedIn API.

I am continuously getting a 400 response.
Where is the error in this approach?

```
const client = new S3Client({region: "eu-west-2", credentials: { accessKeyId: "**accesskeyid", secretAccessKey: "**secretaccesskey**"}});
              
const { Body } = await client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: key,
}));

var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "LinkedIn-Version": "202309",
    "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
};

axios.put(url, Body, {
    headers: headers
})
.then(function(response){
    resolve(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    reject(error);
});
```

I can do this outside of lambda using curl and a local file, this is the command I am trying to replicate:

```
curl -i --upload-file **thefile** -H 'Authorization: Bearer **token**' "**theurl**"
```

Cloudwatch is returning:

```
"message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (file:///var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)\n    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (file:///var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)\n    at Unzip.emit (node:events:529:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Is it the retrieval from S3, or the sending to LinkedIn? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: This is the caught error:{
  "errorType": "AxiosError",
  "errorMessage": "Request failed with status code 400",
  "trace": [
    "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400",
    "    at settle (file:///var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)",
    "    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (file:///var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)",
    "    at Unzip.emit (node:events:529:35)",
    "    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)",
    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"
  ]
}

Comment: **Side-note:** You should not be including any credentials in your Lambda function. Simply use `new S3Client()` and it will automatically retrieve credentials from the **IAM Role** assigned to the Lambda function. This won't fix the Axios error, but it is a 'more correct' way to write an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: 400 likely means that the LinkedIn API rejected your request because it was malformed in some way. Which LinkedIn API is this and does it actually support PUT or does it require POST?

Comment: Maybe the returned S3 object is not valid, thus making the LinkedIn API rejects your request with 400. 
What is the `Body` containing? Is it actually retrieving the body of the S3 object?
If you output it with `console.log(Body)`, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is caused by passing the result of GetOjectCommand directly to your API request.

```
axios.put(url, Body, {
    headers: headers
})
```

You should parse the response from S3 and ensure you only pass the necessary information to your LinkedIn API call.